# The requested URL was not found on ubuntu linode 16.04 lts

Tags: php, apache2.4

I have hosted a codeigniter website on linode 2gb ubuntu 16.04 lts with apache2+ php7.0 etc.
Home page works fine but when I try to open any other link from my site it shows the error:

```
The requested URL /BtaClient/get_pbu_by_limit was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.bta.org.pk Port 80
```

The link of my web is: www.bta.org.pk

I check the following:

- modrewrite module is enabled in apache2 and loaded
- .htaccess has these rules:

  ```
  <Directory "/var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  ```
- My virtual host setting:

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.bta.org.pk
      ServerAlias bta.org.pk
      ServerAdmin bta.org.pk@gmail.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html
      #LogLevel info ssl:warn
      ErrorLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/error.log
      CustomLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/access.log combined
      </VirtualHost>
  # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
  ```
- My apache.conf file is:

  ```
  # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
  # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
  # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
  # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
  # hints.
  #
  #
  # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
  # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
  # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
  # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
  # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
  # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
  # possible.

  # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
  # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
  #
  #   /etc/apache2/
  #   |-- apache2.conf
  #   |   `--  ports.conf
  #   |-- mods-enabled
  #   |   |-- *.load
  #   |   `-- *.conf
  #   |-- conf-enabled
  #   |   `-- *.conf
  #   `-- sites-enabled
  #       `-- *.conf
  #
  #
  # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
  #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
  #   web server.
  #
  # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
  #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
  #   customized anytime.
  #
  # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
  #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
  #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
  #   respectively.
  #
  #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
  #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
  #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
  #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
  #
  # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
  #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
  #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
  #   work with the default configuration.


  # Global configuration
  #

  #
  # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
  # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
  #
  # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
  # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
  # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
  # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
  #
  # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
  #
  #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

  #
  # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
  #
  Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

  #
  # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
  # identification number when it starts.
  # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
  #
  PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

  #
  # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
  #
  Timeout 300

  #
  # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
  # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
  #
  KeepAlive On

  #
  # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
  # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
  # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
  #
  MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

  #
  # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
  # same client on the same connection.
  #
  KeepAliveTimeout 5


  # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
  User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
  Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

  #
  # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
  # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
  # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
  # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
  # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
  # nameserver.
  #
  HostnameLookups Off

  # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
  # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
  # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
  # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
  # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
  #
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  #
  # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
  # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
  # error, crit, alert, emerg.
  # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
  # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
  #
  LogLevel warn

  # Include module configuration:
  IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
  IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

  # Include list of ports to listen on
  Include ports.conf


  # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
  # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
  # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
  # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
  # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
  # access here, or in any related virtual host.
  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  #<Directory /srv/>
  #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  #   AllowOverride None
  #   Require all granted
  #</Directory>




  # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
  # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
  # directive.
  #
  AccessFileName .htaccess

  #
  # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
  # viewed by Web clients.
  #
  <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
      Require all denied
  </FilesMatch>


  #
  # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
  # a CustomLog directive.
  #
  # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
  # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
  # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
  # requests.
  #
  # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
  # Use mod_remoteip instead.
  #
  LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
  LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
  LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

  # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
  # see README.Debian for details.

  # Include generic snippets of statements
  IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

  # Include the virtual host configurations:
  IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

  # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
  ```

Comment: Are you running a CMS? Does that CMS possibly expect some kind of rewrite in a `.htaccess` or similar?

Comment: not dear, it's not a CMS, but php framework. direct url are also working, like http://www.bta.org.pk/phpinfo.php

Comment: Which PHP-framework? A lot of frameworks/CMS expects some sort of rewrites.

Comment: thanks! i'm using codeigniter framework . now i got actual problem. .htaccess file not working i have  used above mentioned .htaccess rules but not working fine. what to do?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `AllowOverride None` set. This effectively disables .htaccess, so the rewrite rules does not work.

You need at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` in the `<Directory /var/www>` section - or you can move the rewrite rules into the vhost and keep the `AllowOverride None`.

### Rewrite in vhost configuration

If you want to rewrite your vhost, remove the .htaccess in the codeigniter directory, and change your vhost to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html>
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.bta.org.pk
    ServerAlias bta.org.pk
    ServerAdmin bta.org.pk@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

This is the **best** option, as an attacker that does not gain root cannot change settings, and it is slightly faster, as Apache does not have to look up .htaccess.

### Stick to .htaccess

To keep using .htaccess, change your .htaccess to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And change your vhost to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.bta.org.pk
    ServerAlias bta.org.pk
    ServerAdmin bta.org.pk@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/public_html
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/bta.org.pk/logs/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

This is probably the easiest, and will work.

Comment: vidarlo dear.. thanks a lot . it's working very fine ... again thank you

Comment: That's good :) Then you should consider marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: yes off course. your answer help me a lot . i was start searching the solution  about two days ago but in vain. but you help me ... thnx :)